# What does Klingon Captain Nu'Daq say when losing the B'aht Qul challenge to Data?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, klingon-language

In TNG's "The Chase", Nu'Daq challenges Data to the B'aht Qul and loses. He utters something after this that I cannot find online, except in a transcript that suggests he says "Maw' tok!"

A reference clip can be found here, with the utterance at 0:51:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/246.txt)

> NU'DAQ: (counting in Klingon) Wa'... Cha'... Wej --
>
> Data puts him down without the slightest strain.
>
> NU'DAQ: (amazed) **Maw' tok.**

The [KlingonWiki](http://www.klingonwiki.net/En/Surprise) (and various other sources) simply refer to it as ***an exclamation of surprise.***

Comment: It makes sense that an exclamation of surprise/admiration has a similar-sounding root (with a different modifier) to ["petaQ"](http://www.klingonwiki.net/En/Cursing), an exclamation of disdain.

Comment: It's worth noting - as is mentioned on the wiki page - that this is an example of "Paramount Hol", which is to say that it has been used in a licensed Star Trek production (and is thus canon in the eyes of most Star Trek fans), but is not considered canon by most Klingon-speakers, and doesn't really conform to the language which we speak.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Klingon translator](https://www.translator.eu/english/klingon/translation/), it seems to mean "one of madness".

I typed in "Maw' toch!".